# Conditional expectation given independance and $0$ conditional expectation.

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation

If $e_1,e_2$ are independant random variables and
$\mathbb E[e_i|X_i]=0, i=1,2$ where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are also independant. Is it true that
$$\mathbb E[e_1e_2|\sigma(X_1, X_2)]=\mathbb E[e_1|X_1]\mathbb E[e_2|X_2]=0.$$

**Edit** I also assume that $e_1$ is independant of $X_2$ and $e_2$ of $X_1$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $\{e_1,e_2\}$ be i.i.d , $X_1=e_2$ and $X_2=e_1$. Then $E[e_i|X_i]=0, i=1,2$ but $E[e_1e_2|\sigma (X_1,X_2)]=E[e_1e_2|\sigma (e_1,e_2)]=e_1e_2$.

Comment: What if $e_1$ is also independant of $X_2$ and $e_2$ of $X_1$

Comment: It is still false.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B_1$ and $B_2$ be two Borel sets, then:
\begin{align}\mathbb E[e_1e_2 1_{\{X_1\in B_1 X_2\in B_2\}}]&= \mathbb E[e_1 1_{\{X_1 \in B_1\}} e_21_{\{X_2 \in B_2\}}]\\
&=\mathbb E[e_1 1_{\{X_1 \in B_1\}}]\mathbb E[ e_21_{\{X_2 \in B_2\}}] \\
&= \mathbb E[\mathbb E[e_1|X_1] 1_{\{X_1 \in B_1\}}]\mathbb E[ \mathbb E[e_2|X_2]1_{\{X_2 \in B_2\}}]\\
&=0\end{align}